# Does Tridev get angry when they are not worshipped?

Tags: gods, pralaya

Does Vishnu and Shiva gets angry when people on earth not worship them ? I am asking this I was thinking what will happen when Hinduism gets weakned in future , Will the gods destroy the world ? As world would become meaningless and purposeless.

Late Tarek Fateh [said something](https://twitter.com/aquibmir71/status/1650539613273079816) indicating the same.

Comment: In Gita, there is a line where Kṛṣṇa says that He neither favours nor hates anybody. Case closed. Hindus don't think of God as some sort of 'jealous' entity like Yahweh.

Comment: @অনু Anger of gods is different from anger of humans. Shiva got angry on ganesha and beheaded him , doesn't mean he is insecure person who got angry on a little child. Everything by gods is planned for some higher purpose.